# Login with Devise via jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

We have a working app using Devise for authentication (email, password).

To add the mobile interface we're using jQuery mobile — everything works fine, except the login via Devise won't behave.

After hitting “login” Rails processes the request correctly but all we get is a MissingTemplate (devise/sessions/create) error.

---

Current settings:

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_hxr = false

config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]
```

---

We're inspired by Railscast #199 (hence `:mobile`): http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwriting Devise's `SessionsController` works. I took the controller's code from [github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) and added the redirect_to for mobile devices:

`app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    if mobile_device?
      redirect_to wherever_you_want
    else
      respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
    end
  end
end
```

And in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '/', :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

Don't forget to create `app/views/sessions/` templates.

Answer (score 7):

Try the last step in this guide [How To: Make Devise work with other formats like mobile, iphone and ipad (Rails specific)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Make-Devise-work-with-other-formats-like-mobile,-iphone-and-ipad-%28Rails-specific%29).

Remember to use :to_mobile instead of :to_ios,
so:

```
ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end
```

in a new initializer file in config/initializers

Comment: Note that following these instructions there was no need to change config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check this article

[jQuery Mobile, Rails, and Devise](http://everydayrails.com/2010/11/09/jquery-mobile-rails-devise.html)

In my application i've added new view devise/sessions/create.mobile.erb and set in this view javascript redirect on certain page. This is look like not a right solution, but it works.

Comment: Ole's initializer above seems to be the best solution.